# Batch: Write String from .txt between double quotes to .txt

Tags: batch-file, cmd, findstr

I am about to write a batch-file to get lines from a textfile and write only the content between two "" (double quotes) to another textfile.

e.q. fileinput:

```
    WRITE    1,48,1,"1> MODUL 2 TYPENKONTROLLE "
    WRITE    1,56,1,"2> MODUL 6 PRAEGETIEFE    "
    Some other text...
    WRITE    1,64,1,"__________________________"
```

fileoutput:

```
    "1> MODUL 2 TYPECONTROLE   "
    "2> MODUL 6 PRAEGETIEFE    "
    "__________________________"
```

my not working batch:

```
@echo File:
set /p file=
FOR /F delims^=^" %%i in ('findstr -i -r -c:"[\"]^" %file%.txt') do (
echo %%i >> %file%strings.txt 
)
```

I think i need something like this:

```
@echo File:
set /p file=
FOR /F delims^=^" tokens^=1,2 %%i in ('findstr -i -r -c:"[\"]^" %file%.txt') do (    
echo %%i not needed!
echo %%j >> %file%strings.txt 
)
```

Can someone help me with my problem?

Comment: The solution of rojo is working fine. I am adding some functions at the moment.
I would really like to use grep cause i like it on linux. but my company dont want to give me a linux pc, only Win x64... sad :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking for a pure batch solution, then this is probably all you need. It uses nasty looking escape sequences in the FOR /F options to allow specification of `"` as your token delimiter.

```
@echo off
>"output.txt" (
  for /f usebackq^ tokens^=2^ delims^=^" %%A in ("input.txt") do echo "%%A" 
)
```

If you want to make sure that the closing quote is present, then you can add FINDSTR to your DO clause. FINDSTR expects quotes to be escaped as `\"`.

```
@echo off
>"output.txt" (
  for /f usebackq^ tokens^=2^ delims^=^" %%A in ('findstr \".*\" "input.txt"') do echo "%%A" 
)
```

The above solutions only write the first quoted string from any line. Additional quoted strings are ignored.

But I usually use my [JREPL.BAT regular expression text utility](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6044) to manipulate text. It is a hybrid JScript/batch script that runs natively on any Windows machine from XP onward.

Assuming your PATH includes a folder that contains JREPL.BAT, then all you need is the following from the command line:

```
jrepl "\q.*?\q" $0 /x /jmatch /f input.txt /o output.txt
```

Since JREPL is a batch script, you need to use CALL JREPL if you use the command within another batch script.

Note that the above JREPL solution writes out every quoted string on a separate line, even if there are two quoted strings within the same source line. If you only want the first quoted string from any line, then the solution becomes

```
jrepl "(\q.*?\q).*" $1 /x /jmatch /f input.txt /o output.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution would be to use grep.  You'd need the [binaries and dependencies](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/grep.htm).  Then you could just

```js
grep -E -o "\".+\"" infile.txt > outfile.txt
```

to get the output you want.

The difficulty in accomplishing this in pure batch is that batch treats quotation marks as token delimiters.  Some of the lines containing redirect symbols (the `>` symbol) further complicates matters.  Although it's not easy to treat the quotation marks and `>` symbols as independent characters, it is possible.

```js
@echo off
setlocal

>outfile.txt (
    (
        for /f "usebackq delims=" %%I in ("infile.txt") do (
            call :get_stuff_between_quotes %%I
        )
    )
)

goto :EOF
:: // END MAIN RUNTIME

:: // get_stuff_between_quotes function
:: // echoes stuff between (and including) quotation marks
:: // echoes nothing if no quotation marks in argument
:get_stuff_between_quotes
:: // use delayed expansion to prevent evaluation of >
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set line=%*

:: // strip everything before first quotation mark
set line=!line:*"=!

:: // if line is unchanged, it didn't contain quotation marks.
if "!line!"=="%*" endlocal & goto :EOF

:: // otherwise, re-echo the leading quotation mark + the rest of the line
echo("!line!
endlocal & goto :EOF
```

Although, in my not so humble opinion, the `grep` solution is much easier to follow.